# Printing a book - text on odd numbered pages with even numbered pages left blank

Tags: blank-page

Printing a book - text on odd numbered pages with even numbered pages left blank. Is it possible to get this style in LaTeX in an automated way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert arbitrary text at shipout time using [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi)'s `\AtBeginShipout{<code>}`. As `<code>` we insert some non-printing content `\mbox{}` and then flush the page `\clearpage`. Executing this code during shipout inserts a blank page:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \mbox{}% Insert something blank on a page
    %\thispagestyle{empty}% remove header/footer
    \clearpage% Flush page
  \fi
}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Since each blank page is just a regular page (with the default header/footer), you can issue `\thispagestyle{empty}` (or another page style) to change this.

Comment: Is it possible to print the figures and tables only on the verso pages?

Comment: @venkatesanRamachandiran: Probably, but now you're forcing floats to not float. So if you're willing to perform some manual placement, then sure...